# Keeping background the same when sliding activities with overridependingtransition()

Tags: java, android, animation, slide

I am sliding from one activity to another by using this code.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_out_left);
```

This works great when the backgrond is a solid color.  But, my background is not a solid color.  Below is my background.

[image]

So when this background slides from right to left, you notice the transition.  I want the only thing to be noticed that is moving are the Buttons, TextViews, etc.  How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Based on Matt's comments (another Matt, not me) I created a Splash Activity and set the background of it to the clouds background.  I then removed the clouds background from all the other activities.  When the SplashScreen transitions to the MainMenu class, here is what displays:

[image]

So basically I am seeing the homescreen of the emulator where all the apps reside.  Below is my new `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category 
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Levels"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

I added this to my `styles.xml`.

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT #2**

I am slowly making progress.  Now the SplashScreen launches and then transitions into the MainActivity perfectly.  The transitions to other screens, for example when I click the Play button, is not quite correct yet.  They transition without the background changing but the previous transparent activity stays there and all the transparent activities start stacking on top of each other.  Is there a way to "dismiss" the transparent activities when a new intent/activity is started so they don't overlap and stack on top of each other?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to preserve something in the Background with that image (Maybe an Activity) then set the activities to slide over it with the theme @style/Theme.Transparent

Comment: I am heading out for the weekend and won't be able to test this for several days.  Will report back then.

Comment: I am not sure how to do what you suggested.  Could you provide me with something further if you can?  Otherwise, I still need assistance.

Comment: Have you applied the Transparent theme to your Activities? Can you see something other than black behind them after the application? Once you get there, you'll want to create something like a "SplashActivity" to launch on Startup as your background.

Comment: Amazing -- looks good. Now create an Activity that only contains one full-screen ImageView (your background) and launch that BEFORE you launch your main Activity... Will the ImageView Activity stay up even after you launch your main Activity? You may need to do something like overridePendingTransitions() to make sure it doesn't slide out, I'm not sure...

Comment: Please see the edit to my opening post.  Thank you for being patient and helping me through this!

Comment: I figured it out.  All I had to do to fix the last issue was add `finish()` to "dismiss" the activities.  Thanks Matt!

Comment: Please keep in mind that Android is "allowed" to kill that "Background" Activity almost at any time. I'd recommend doing something to keep it active, like re-launching it periodically, or catch onDestroy() [or similar] to ensure it's always present.

Comment: Ok no problem, I will look into fixing that.